# Document on click event not firing

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am fetching the image details from database and showing them in grid format.
Here is the code.

```
<div ng-repeat="imageUrl in images" class="col-xs-3 img-wrap">

  <span class="close" id="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope id="grid"   >

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" >

    <a href="{{imageUrl}}" id="thumb" name="{{pid[$index]}}" class="thumbnail " itemprop="contentUrl"  data-id="{{pid[$index]}}" data-size="800x600"> 
    <img src="" class="img-responsive " data-id="{{pid[$index]}}" id="{{pid[$index]}}" ng-src="{{thumb[$index]}}" style="min-height:50px;height:50px;">
    </a>

    </figure>

</div>
</div>
```

It is working properly. I have added a delete button **(x)** like this to delete the image. Once user click on the cross button I am planning to run ajax code to delete the image from server.

So, basically I want the click event to delete the image. I tried jQuery code but that is not working. If possible please advise me on an Angular way as I don't want to use jQuery.

```
$('#close').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.img-wrap').find('img').data('id');
    alert('remove picture: ' + id);
    alert('test');
});
```

Tried this as well.

```
$('.img-wrap .closer').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.img-wrap').find('img').data('id');
    alert('remove picture: ' + id);
    alert('test');
});
```

**Edit:** I am tried ng-click event and it is working but I want to know how can I hide the respective image in ngclick.

```
$scope.myFunc = function(btnId) {
            alert(btnId);


    };
```

Comment: try using ng-click

Comment: Ids must be unique so you shouldn't have ids in elements that are created in a loop. In any case you should be binding click events with Angular instead of jQuery.

Comment: @Pbd and jjj any example relevant to this will be much appreciated.

Comment: would love to give example, but angular is bit rusty. I can only encourage to read throught the ng-click documentation and tell that they have good example to get you started.

Comment: Surely the Internet is full of examples. Does googling for "angular click event" really not bring up anything?

Comment: well let me try but having hard time with angular unfortunately.

Comment: just check their website. Also, your problem can't be re-produced, so nobody will risk answering

Comment: all things working properly. just stuck at hiding respective image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have pointed out in the question, jQuery is not the correct way to do this, you should be using angular.

You can pass arguments to an `ng-click` function, and this is how you can pass the id.

```
<span class="close" id="close" ng-click="remove(pid[$index])">&times;</span>
```

And in your controller

```
function remove(id) {
  alert('remove picture: ' + id);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to hide respective image. can you help in that.

Comment: Remove it from the array of images that you're using with `ng-repeat`. Presumably each image has an id - use lodash or Array.prototype.filter to remove image by id.